# Get javascript array variable in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I call the jsp page with passing the parameter as array variable

```
var textval1=new Array(),questions1=new Array(),txt1=new Array();
```

and i call the jsp page like this using the javascript code.

```
var jspcall = ("new1.jsp?graph="+txt1+"&text="+textval1+"&ques="+questions1);
document.getElementById('frames').src=jspcall;
```

The jsp page is load with in the iframe and its id is frames.

I retrive this element in jsp page like.

```
String[] graph = request.getParameter("graph");
String[] answer1 = request.getParameter("text");
String[] ques = request.getParameter("ques");
```

But it shows me a error can anybody help this to retrive the array value.

Comment: [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter\(java.lang.String\)) returns a `String`, not a `String[]`. Start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] graph = request.getParameterValues("graph"); 
String[] answer1 = request.getParameterValues("text");
String[] ques = request.getParameterValues("ques");
```

Comment: Look now! getParameterValues!